# SessionId lost when I make a request between backend of microservices

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, microservices

I am trying to make request between microservices in order to retrieve a list of users with the same roles. For this, first I make a request between FrontEnd and Backend inside the microservice 1. Following, I call an endpoint in the microservice 2 from Microservice 1 backend, but the session Id is lost in it, and I can retrieve the context. 
I am using spring security and Redis for the session Control. 
Manually, I retrieve the session Id from the microservice 1 and I add it as an attribute of the header of the second call, to the microservice 2. But it does not work.

```
String sessionID= RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers= new HttpHeaders();            
headers.set("Session",sessionID);
HttpEntity<ResponseData> entity = new HttpEntity<ResponseData>(headers);
ResponseEntity<ResponseData> responseEntity =rest.exchange(targetApi,  HttpMethod.GET, entity,ResponseData.class);
```

[image]

Comment: Copy all headers (may have auth info) as well as cookies (session normally added to cookie). BTW if 2 services work on different JVM they may have no common session at all

Comment: Both are in the same JVM, the session is controlled by Redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the problem adding an interceptor as a component:

```
@Component
public class SpringSessionClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
    throws IOException {

    request.getHeaders().add("Cookie", "SESSION=" + sessionId);
    return execution.execute(request, body);
}
```

}

And I created a @Bean to configure the rest template:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    ClientHttpRequestInterceptor interceptor= new SpringSessionClientHttpRequestInterceptor();
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add(interceptor);
    rest.setInterceptors(interceptors);  
    return rest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to your question but in terms of your design I'd question if you really want to make your microservice1 depending on microsevice2. A microservice should be autonomous in the way it works and being able to be deployed on it's own (in theory anyway!). May be you could have an orchestrating microservice that receives your session information and then calls the 2 other microservices to pass that information on via 'standard' attributes.

Comment: Microservice1 is totally autonomous, it is able to be deployed on is own, but it offers a service that needs some information from microservice2

Answer (score 0):

> headers.set("Session",sessionID);

I assume that the problem is that you are using the wrong identifier. As far as I know, it is JSESSIONID by default.

Another problem that I can see here is that JSESSIONID expected to be in cookies. Try to put it in cookies when sending a request to your 'microservice2'.